# Can I use walletnotify or blocknotify remotely with a NodeJS application?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, javascript, node.js, wallet-notify

I'd like to get information from my bitcoin node running on a cloud server to be used to make changes in my NodeJS app running on my computer. So, in the bitcoin.conf file, should I have something like `walletnotify=curl http://My.IP.Address:PortAppUses/walletnotify.js?tx=%s`? If that's right, what do I write in the walletnotify.js file to simply save the incoming transaction id as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are telling it to place the transaction id as a GET request in the URI under the tx parameter.

```
walletnotify=curl http://My.IP.Address:PortAppUses/walletnotify.js?tx=%s
```

All you would need to do inside of `walletnotify.js` is pull the `tx` GET, in nodejs express that would be something like:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const request = require("request");

app.get("/", function(req, res){

    let transactionId = req.query.tx;

    //do whatever with transactionId

});
```

Comment: I already got it, but I appreciate it! Love your YouTube, by the way!